# Использование функций при нахождении делителей

Tags: python, функции

Есть задание по Питону:
Напишите функцию, которая принимает целое число (предварительно полученное от пользователя) и выводит на экран значения его делителей до 10. Например, для 6 будет вывод: 2, 3, 6; а для 20 будет вывод: 2, 4, 5, 10.

Формат вывода: "is divisible by: n", где n -- соответствующий делитель. Выводите каждый делитель в отдельной строке.

Сделать это нужно без цикла, использования массивов, словарей, списков. Это реально?
Никакой код я не написала, так как не представляю как это реализовать.
Заранее благодарю за подсказки.

Comment: а списковые включения использовать можно? если да, то вот вам и подсказка.

Comment: Любой цикл можно заменить рекурсией. Скорее всего, подразумевался именно этот вариант, судя по акценту на использовании функций.

Comment: Какие массивы в python? Их там нет. @strawdog, а списковое включение без использования списка — это как?

Comment: @Глеб, списки в Python - это массивы. То что автор языка их по недоразумению назвал списками не отменяет этого факта.

Comment: @Глеб это очень просто - range. и списковое включение можно не возвращать в массив, а просто выводить.

Comment: Чтобы избежать цикла в явном виде ещё можно `map` использовать, не исключаю, что может этот вариант имелся в виду )

Comment: @CrazyElf Ну там же iterable, нужно

Comment: @Oopss Ну вроде ограничения на использование `range` не было )  Но ваш способ с рекурсией безусловно тоже подходит, я за него проголосовал.

Comment: @strawdog
списковые включения также не подходят. На текущий момент дан материал по типам данным, условным конструкциям и на сегодня функции. Я так понимаю ответ от  Oopss не подходит?

Comment: @Глеб, насчёт *массивов* - вот вам [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#array.array).

Comment: @insolor Ну всё-таки питоновский список - это хоть и массив там внутри, но используется этот контейнер как список всё-равно. Просто он оптимизирован за счёт лежащего внутри массива. Кстати, в `C#` устройство списков такое же по сути, только стратегия расширения при достижении `capacity` немного другая. И ещё в `C#` можно свою `capacity` сразу при объявлении списка указать. А так всё-таки под массивом обычно понимают не расширяемую коллекцию, а у питоновского списка основная фича именно возможность бесконечного расширения.

Comment: @CrazyElf, ну нет. В Computre Science массив (вектор) - это когда элементы хранятся в памяти рядом друг с другом. Динамическая расширяемость не делает массив менее массивом. Связный список — когда элементы хранятся распределенно по памяти (не обязательно подряд) со ссылками между элементами. В Python списки — это именно динамические массивы. На самом деле тут не о чем спорить, но и не нужно под каждым первым постом от новичка, назвавшего список массивом писать, что в Python нет массивов (это не к вам, это к Глеб).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А зачем тут вообще циклы? можно просто прописать все числа до 10 в коде (если я, конечно, правильно понял задачу):

```
def f(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        print(...)
    if n % 3 == 0:
        print(...)
    # И так далее до 10
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def f(n,count=2):
    if n==count:
        return None
    else:
        if n%count == 0:
            print(f'{n} is divisible by: {count}')
        return f(n,count+1)
f(int(input('Введите целое число  ')))
```

---

По предложению @CrazyElf, можно рассмотреть еще один вариант:

```
n = int(input())
print(*filter(lambda x: x if n % x == 0 else None, range(2, n)),sep='\n')
```

Comment: Я этого еще не знаю) Выше написала коммент: "На текущий момент дан материал по типам данным, условным конструкциям и на сегодня функции. "

Comment: Первый вариант, это функция.

Comment: спасибо, сейчас буду разбираться в коде

Comment: @Oopss Моё предложение было проще на самом деле - точно такая же обычная функция как у вас, только не рекурсивно вызывается, а делается `map` этой функции на `range` )

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой вариант работает так, как от меня просят:

```py
num = int(input())

def div(num, count=2):
    if num + 1 == count:
        return count
    else:
        if count > 10:
            return
        if num % count == 0:
            print("is divisible by:", count)
        return div(num, count + 1)

div(num)
```

Вывод:

```
is divisible by:  2
is divisible by:  4
is divisible by:  5
is divisible by:  10
```

Всем спасибо за подсказки!

Comment: `if num != count and num == count:` Ну как жеж так?

Comment: @Oopss
Но оно только так работает как надо... Есть идеи?

Comment: Что не так работает если `if num == count:`  и это для чего `if count > 10:
            return`

Comment: Если, например, num=30 то count может быть 15 т.е. больше 10

Comment: А у меня условие задачи, чтобы не превышало 10) Это в вопросе указано

Comment: @Oopss, если убрать выражение if num != count, то при вводе, например, числа 2, 7 ничего не выводится. А с выражением неравенства работает. Мне нужно, чтобы введенное число, если у него есть делитель, даже оно само, отображалось на выводе

Comment: если у него есть делитель, даже оно само, отображалось на выводе `if num+1 == count:`

Comment: @Oopss
 Благодарю!